# Typescript - Use element in array argument as return type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a simple function as follow:

```js
const transform = ([a, b]) => ({operation: a, ...b});
```

How can I type this function to make sure the return type is an object containing a key `operation` with the type of the argument a and the property of b.

I tried the following but without success:

```js
function transform<[A, B]>(param: [A, B]): { operation: A } & B {
    return { operation: param[0], ...param[1] };
}
```

Any help about that? Thanks!

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZrnem)?  Your main problem is writing `function transform<[A, B]>(...)` instead of `function transform<A, B>(...)`; the stuff in the angle brackets is supposed to be type parameter declarations, which is just a comma separated list of type parameter names (possibly with constraints and/or defaults); the fact that you are later going to use these types in some tuple type doesn't change that.  Should I write this up as an answer?  Or was this just a typo?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I didn't get the concept of type parameters. I assumed it was supposed to match the signature of the function parameters. Now I realise my mistake and a lot of Typescript stuff just make a lot more sense now. So thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what amounts to a typographical error; instead of `transform<[A, B]>(...)`, you need to write `transform<A, B>(...)` like this:

```
function transform<A, B>(param: [A, B]): { operation: A } & B {
  //        ----> ^^^^^^         ^  ^  <------------> ^     ^
  // declaring type params         using the type params
  // 
  return { operation: param[0], ...param[1] };
}
```

The `transform()` function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in two *type parameters* `A`, and `B`.  (You can think of these almost like regular function parameters, but instead of corresponding to arguments that callers pass in as *values*, they are arguments that callers pass in as *types*.)  The syntax for **declaring** the list of type parameters a generic function takes is to put a comma-separated list of these parameters inside angle brackets, immediately before the list of regular parameters in parentheses.

It's only later in the function signature and implementation where you **use** the type parameters as types.  So the `param` function parameter is annotated as type `[A, B]`, a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) where the first element is of type `A` and the second element is of type `B`.  The fact that you were going to *use* the type `[A, B]` has nothing to do with the syntax to *declare* the type parameters.

That's the answer to the question as asked.

---

I could go a little further and suggest that a more direct translation of your original `transform` JavaScript code into TypeScript would look like this:

```
const transform = <A, B extends object>(
  [a, b]: [A, B]
): { operation: A } & B => ({ operation: a, ...b });
```

Here you can see that even arrow functions can be generic, and therefore need a type parameter declaration before the parameter list (which must be in parentheses, even if your arrow function looks like `x => x`... you can't write `<T>x:T => x`, you need `<T>(x: T) => x`).  Also see that the return type annotation of an arrow function comes immediately after the parameter list with a colon, and before the arrow `=>`.

Since you are going to use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax) on `b` which of type `B`, it's useful to tell the compiler that `B` should be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type), so that nobody calls `transform([1, 2])` and is possibly confused by what comes out.

Also, you can still use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in your function parameter, so we have `([a, b]: [A, B])` instead of `(param: [A, B])`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIBiAlgB55EkkBmArsPAC40D2wSLgCcQwKC15CwAHgCCAGiQAhAHwAKOCLAAuJAG0FygLoBKXbiS8YEET367ZSAL5IAZMsbFmJAPQ-v3gC0wYEqSAB6kVEB3uEkcUjSIckpYQnM4UwBfkgAJhDwGCBCNMAA5oIAntZImuBQMcxsUKUVXAAWyFzVyHVgUFneOYPMQhBcbEICFlY2IHbAun16AAxGigB0W8sAjEbOANwjTlknhFnw-FBcgiJiElJIALyJhkpIEHRcEMC5DbwAIwAVgUuOoRnoQIoAUZdAZFEojFkzHhLNZbHxFkhHC53O8nmE1DN0fNMbooUgthsAc4TEdzgynEA)